# Connecting Blender Sharder nodes for material

Tags: python

I'm trying to connect some shader noded in code but can't quite figure it out for this specific example. It seems easy enough from what I found online, but after hours of attempts, I'm hoping someone can help me understand why one of my three attempts is not working. The last 3 lines of code are my attempts. the only thing I can think of is I don't have some material or the object selected properly. I hope this is enough of the file, if you need more context from the code in the file I'm happy to share.

in case I'm not using the correct terms, this is what I'm trying to do

[image]

```
def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=6, radius=1.0, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), scale=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    planet = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    planet.name = "Planet"
    planet_material = bpy.data.materials.get("planet material")
    

    if planet_material is None:
        # create material
        planet_material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="planet material")
    planet.data.materials.append(planet_material)
    
    planet_material.use_nodes = True
    nodes = planet_material.node_tree.nodes
    ColorRamp1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')
    ColorRamp1.location = -400,100
    ColorRamp2 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')
    ColorRamp2.location = -700,100
    ColorRamp3 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')
    ColorRamp3.location = -1000,100
    
    Noise1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexNoise')
    Noise1.location = -1100,300
    Noise2 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexNoise')
    Noise2.location = -900,300
    
    Bump = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBump')
    Bump.location = -150,-150


    planet_material.node_tree.links.new(Noise1.outputs[0],Noise2.inputs[1])
    
    planet.active_material.node_tree.links.new(Noise1.outputs[0],Noise2.inputs[1])
    
    planet_material.node_tree.links(Noise1.outputs[0],Noise2.inputs[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first option works and connects the output to `inputs[1]`. However, `inputs[1]` is the W socket, which is only visible for 1D or 4D noise. If you switch to 4D you can see your link.

[image: Link visible]

If you hover over the "Scale" socket (and have "Python Tooltips" enabled in the prefs) you can see it is `inputs[2]`. So this will do what you want.

```
planet_material.node_tree.links.new(Noise1.outputs[0], Noise2.inputs[2])
```

Alternatively, it is usually better to use the socket name anyway, since it's more readable (although it's not possible for every node).

```
planet_material.node_tree.links.new(Noise1.outputs["Fac"], Noise2.inputs["Scale"])
```

Answer (score 0):

with the help of a dev friend, We got this to work.

````
        
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=6, radius=1.0, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), scale=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
        planet = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        planet.name = "Planet"
        planet_material = bpy.data.materials.get("planet material")
       

        if planet_material is None:
            # create material
            planet_material = bpy.data.materials.new(name="planet material")
            
        def clear_material( material ):
            if material.node_tree:
                material.node_tree.links.clear()
                material.node_tree.nodes.clear()
        clear_material(planet_material)    
        
        if not planet_material:
            planet_material = planet_material.new( "planet material" )
            
        planet.data.materials.append(planet_material)
        
        planet_material.use_nodes = True
        nodes = planet_material.node_tree.nodes
        links = planet_material.node_tree.links
        
        planet_material.node_tree.nodes.clear()
               
        Noise1 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexNoise')
        Noise1.location = -1100,300
        Noise2 = nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexNoise')
        Noise2.location = -900,300
        
        
        links.new(Noise1.outputs['Fac'], Noise2.inputs['Vector'])
        
        
```
````

Comment: `if not planet_material:` line will always evaluate the condition to `False`, because you just made sure it is set to a material. So the line can be removed together with indented line below (which is also mostly nonsensical and would cause an error).

`planet_material.node_tree.nodes.clear()` could be changed to `nodes.clear()`. `clear_material` function is never used.